# VBA Splitting the same string multiple times

Tags: string, excel, split, vba

I've been searching the internet and I cannot seem to figure out my problem.  Any help would be much appreciated.  My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub removebutton_Click()
Dim iRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim removebox As String
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")
removebox = InputBox("Please Scan the Barcode to be added", "Add Coin", "Scan Barcode Here")
'Find the next blank row'
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'Promt User To Actually input data if they have not entered anything'
If Trim(Me.removebox.Value) = "" Then
Me.removebox.SetFocus
MsgBox "Please enter barcode"
Exit Sub
End If

'For 20 digit barcodes split into 4 parts and record the data in the next blank row'
If Len(removebox) = 20 Then
Dim s1 As String
s1 = removebox.Substring(1, 6)
Dim s2 As String
s2 = removebox.Substring(7, 8)
Dim s3 As String
s3 = removebox.Substring(9)
Dim s4 As String
s4 = removebox.Substring(10, 20)

ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.s1.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.s2.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.s3.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Me.s4.Value

'For 18 Digit barcodes spilt into 3 parts and record the data in the next blank row'
ElseIf (removebox) = 18 Then
Dim s5 As String
s5 = removebox.Substring(1, 6)
Dim s6 As String
s6 = removebox.Substring(7, 8)
Dim s7 As String
s7 = removebox.Substring(9, 18)

ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.s5.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.s6.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.s7.Value

'If not 20 or 18 digit then it is 16, split into 3 parts and record the data in the next blank row'
Else
Dim s8 As String
s8 = removebox.Substring(1, 6)
Dim s9 As String
s9 = removebox.Substring(7, 8)
Dim s10 As String
s10 = removebox.Substring(9, 16)

ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Me.s8.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Me.s9.Value
ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Me.s10.Value
End If

End Sub
```

So I messed up and the entire Code was supposed to be to remove an item and instead it adds an item I realize that.  My problem is that the `s1 = removebox.Substring(1, 6)` highlights the `removebox` variable and tells me `Compiler Error: Invalid Qualifier`.  If anyone could give me a possible solution, I know I'm doing something wrong but as you scan a bar code it comes in as 20, 18, or 16 digit integer but I need to save the parts separately in order to create an easy look-up function for the database.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head of Catering beat me to it. But I will paste the code since I already worked on it.

> > > A bar code it comes in as 20, 18, or 16 digit integer

**Note**: Based on above, I am not breaking it into 4 equal parts. I have simply converted your existing code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub removebutton_Click()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim removebox As String

    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    removebox = InputBox("Please Scan the Barcode to be added", _
    "Add Coin", "Scan Barcode Here")

    '~~> Prompt User To Actually input data if they have not entered anything
    If Len(Trim(removebox)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Please enter barcode", vbCritical, "Please Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Find the next blank row
    iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

    ws.Cells(iRow, 1).Value = Left(removebox, 6)
    ws.Cells(iRow, 2).Value = Mid(removebox, 7, 8)

    Select Case Len(removebox)
        '~~> For 20 digit barcodes split into 4 parts and record
        '~~> the data in the next blank row'
        Case 20
            ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Mid(removebox, 9)
            ws.Cells(iRow, 4).Value = Mid(removebox, 10, 20)
        '~~> For 18 Digit barcodes spilt into 3 parts and record
        '~~> the data in the next blank row'
        Case 18
            ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Mid(removebox, 9, 18)
        '~~> If not 20 or 18 digit then it is 16, split into 3
        '~~> parts and record the data in the next blank row'
        Case Else
            ws.Cells(iRow, 3).Value = Mid(removebox, 9, 18)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you both SOOO much!  You just saved me!  I really appreciate your willingness to help someone who is still trying to figure things out!  (Head of Catering I attempted to @ you in this as well but I was not allowed to)

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Now just don't copy it ;) Try and understand how it works :)

Comment: I am ^_^, thanks again.  Although for some reason my search for the next blank row is now somehow broke.  It keeps telling me "Run Time Error '91': Object Variable or With block not set", any ideas?

Comment: physically check if sheet1 is empty or not? You should have at least 1st row filled with headers. Alternatively you can use this `iRow = ws.Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row + 1"` to find the next row.

Comment: Glad to help Mike. Good luck with your app.